# Are these both sentences correct?

Tags: grammar

It's about permission.
1)May I use your phone, please?
2) could I use your phone; please?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["May I have a glass of water" vs. "Can I have a glass of water": which is better, "may I" or "can I", when asking for something?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/95299/may-i-have-a-glass-of-water-vs-can-i-have-a-glass-of-water-which-is-better)

Comment: It's about permission, so  are both connect to express a permission using:- may and could?

Comment: Take a look at the suggested duplicates. Do they answer your question?  If not then please explain why not.

Comment: Why are you asking this question? Why do you think these sentences might be correct? Why do you think these might be incorrect? What research have you already done?